# javascript on change save form

Tags: forms, onchange

I've got a problem with some code, the intention is to save data from a form to a database on change.

The on change code uses an existing function to save the form but there seems to be a problem since it does not save the data consistently. If the save button is used and there is a change made you are prompted to resend the data from the form and if you do so the old data shows up in the form.

The code looks like this:

```js
$('#Form').on("change",function()
{
    var dataString = $('#Form').serialize() + '&submit_save=Save';
    $.post("test.php", dataString, function(inData)
    {
        window.alert(dataString);
        window.location.reload();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You have several typos in you code, try to correct them first

Comment: typos taken care of, they where not in the running code.